# How update angular-ui-grid row with streaming data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on a trading application and am using Angularjs and ui-grid for data blotter. I have to update my grid rows with high frequency streaming data coming from a callback of message queue(callback will not trigger digest cycle of its own). On each update, I have to update few properties of one of the rendered grid row. After each update, I cannot call $scope.$digest, as then my UI will be just busy with the digest cycles. How do I tell ui-grid to just update a specific row. If my understanding is correct, UI-Grid maintains an isolated scope for each row. I tried calling notifyDataChange API with dataChange.ROW , but it does not work. (Also, the notifyDataChange api refreshes the entire grid). 
Any advice ?

Comment: To make it clear, I want to specifically refresh a grid row scope in ui-grid.

Comment: If the number of records are more, ui grid is not a good option. Btw if you don't require any export, selecting functionalities, better to go with plain ng-repeat and create the table. It might give a better performence.